# module installed with librarian puppet is not found

Tags: vagrant, puppet

I'm trying to install puppetlabs apt module inside a vagrant guest, but I'm hitting the following error:

```
==> default: Running provisioner: puppet...
==> default: Running Puppet with default.pp...
==> default: stdin: is not a tty
==> default: Info: Loading facts in /tmp/modules/puppetlabs-stdlib/lib/facter/pe_version.rb
==> default: Info: Loading facts in /tmp/modules/puppetlabs-stdlib/lib/facter/puppet_vardir.rb
==> default: Info: Loading facts in /tmp/modules/puppetlabs-stdlib/lib/facter/facter_dot_d.rb
==> default: Info: Loading facts in /tmp/modules/puppetlabs-stdlib/lib/facter/root_home.rb
==> default: Info: Loading facts in /tmp/modules/puppetlabs-apt/lib/facter/apt_package_updates.rb
==> default: Info: Loading facts in /tmp/modules/puppetlabs-apt/lib/facter/apt_update_last_success.rb
==> default: Info: Loading facts in /tmp/modules/puppetlabs-apt/lib/facter/apt_security_updates.rb
==> default: Info: Loading facts in /tmp/modules/puppetlabs-apt/lib/facter/apt_updates.rb
==> default: Error: Could not find class apt for vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64.home on node vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64.home
```

My Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"

  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "apt-get install -y ruby1.9.1-dev git"
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "gem install librarian-puppet -v 1.0.0"
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "cp /vagrant/Puppetfile /tmp/"
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "cd /tmp/ && librarian-puppet install --verbose"

  config.vm.provision "puppet" do |puppet|
    puppet.temp_dir = "/tmp"
    puppet.options = ['--modulepath=/tmp/modules', '--verbose', '--debug']
  end
end
```

My Puppetfile:

```
forge "https://forge.puppetlabs.com"

mod 'puppetlabs-apt',
  :git => "git://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-apt.git"

mod 'puppetlabs-stdlib',
  :git => "git://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-stdlib.git"
```

My manifests/default.pp:

```
include apt
```

I'm inexperienced with puppet so any pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: From my experience `librarian-puppet` installs to `$PWD/modules` so if your `Puppetfile` is in `/tmp` and you run `librarian-puppet`, the `apt` module will end up in `/tmp/modules/apt`. whats the output of `puppet config print modulepath`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

librarian-puppet is putting the modules in /tmp/modules/puppetlabs-apt instead of /tmp/modules/apt

You need to update librarian-puppet to 1.1.3+ because 1.0.0 doesn't use the owner-module syntax, it was owner/module before.

Comment: your gem is awesome.  It makes handling puppet modules from vagrant so easy!